# How to include layout to SonataAdminBundle tab with use sonata_type_admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I use Symfony2 with SonataAdminBundle, and I have a problem where I add a Tab with sonata_type_admin Entity edit. If I go to Entity edit page - all right, but if I add field in OneToOne relationship on tab layout not loaded and all in one style.

Reading documentation not help me, I don't found this decision of this problem in settings. Please, help me.

Main object edit

```
$formMapper
        ->tab('Основная информация')
            ->with('Данные клуба', ['class' => 'col-md-8'])
                ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Название'))
                ->add('alias', 'text', array('label' => 'alias в url на сайте'))
                ->add('logo', 'text', ['label' => 'Логотип'])
                ->add('description', 'textarea', ['label' => 'Описание клуба'])
            ->end()
            ->with('Основные настройки', ['class' => 'col-md-4'])
                ->add('type', 'entity', [
                        'label' => 'Тип клуба',
                        'class' => 'PbmozgSiteBundle:ClubType',
                        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) {return $repository->createQueryBuilder('ClubType')->orderBy('ClubType.id', 'ASC');},
                        'property' => 'name',
                        'empty_value' => 'Выберите тип клуба',
                        'required' => false
                    ]
                )
                ->add('enabled', 'checkbox', ['label' => 'Включен'])
                ->add('vip', 'checkbox', ['label' => 'VIP'])
                ->add('rating', 'text', [
                        'label' => 'Рейтинг клуба',
                        'read_only' => true,
                        'disabled'  => true,
                    ]
                )
            ->end()
        ->end()
        ->tab('Контактная информация')
            ->with('Контакты')
                ->add('contacts', 'sonata_type_admin', ['required' => false, 'delete' => false, 'btn_add' => false])
            ->end()
        ->end();
    ;
```

[image: Main object with sonata_type_admin]

And subobject with add data

```
$formMapper
        ->with('Способы связи', ['class' => 'col-md-4'])
            ->add('phones', 'collection',
                [
                    'label' => 'Телефоны',
                    'type' => new ClubPhonesListType(),
                    'required' => false,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'emails-list'],
                    'options' => ['label' => ' ', 'required' => false],
                ],
                [
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
                ])
            ->add('emails', 'collection',
                [
                    'label' => 'Электронная почта',
                    'type' => new ClubEmailsListType(),
                    'required' => false,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'emails-list'],
                    'options' => ['label' => ' ', 'required' => false],
                ],
                [
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
                ])
        ->end()
        ->with('Геоданные', ['class' => 'col-md-4'])
            ->add('latitude', 'text', ['label' => 'Широта'])
            ->add('longitude', 'text', ['label' => 'Долгота'])
            ->add('polygon', 'text', ['label' => 'Полигон на карте'])
            ->add('country', 'text', ['label' => 'Город'])
            ->add('region', 'text', ['label' => 'Регион'])
            ->add('city', 'text', ['label' => 'Город'])
            ->add('address', 'text', ['label' => 'Полный адрес'])
        ->end()
        ->with('WEB', ['class' => 'col-md-4'])
            ->add('site', 'text', ['label' => 'Адрес сайта'])
        ->end()
    ;
```

[image: View in singe edit]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I found this :

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_create_edit.html#formgroup-options

Section 8.2 :

To do:

```
how to embed one Admin in another (1:1, 1:M, M:M)
```

So, I think for the moment there are no solution ? :/

Comment: Yes. This problem is not have a solution.